# Wish to prevent agent closing tab in service console

Tags: apex, javascript, developer-console, javascript-controller

I am trying to find a way to stop agents from closing their tabs in service console if they have unsaved changes in tab. I am using sforce.console.setTabUnsavedChanges to accomplish this. I know i cannot change the message. When user clicks 'x' on tab it displays dialog box with message and buttons 'Continue' and 'Cancel'. Now the browser has unsaved changes and if user click continue button it closes the tab.

I want that tab user should not be able to close tab until they save the changes on the page.

Is there a way to accomplish this.

Thanks
Nitesh